# Use PIG to count the number of records in an avro file

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, avro

I can open a avro file in HUE and HUE shows me it has 10 records. i can browse through all the 10 records in HUE.

Now I write the following code in PIG

```
data = LOAD '/user/admin/2015/10/04/02/file1.avro' USING AvroStorage();
data_group = GROUP data ALL;
row_count = FOREACH data_group GENERATE COUNT(data);
dump row_count;
```

The output of the job is

```
Input(s):
Successfully read 4 records (58507 bytes) from: "/user/admin/2015/10/04/02/file1.avro"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 1 records (6 bytes) in: "hdfs://nn1/tmp/temp-268177355/tmp915757783"

Counters:
Total records written : 1
Total bytes written : 6
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_1438959478020_940907


2015-10-29 19:08:55,252 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Success!
2015-10-29 19:08:55,252 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.deprecation - fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
2015-10-29 19:08:55,253 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.data.SchemaTupleBackend - Key [pig.schematuple] was not set... will not generate code.
2015-10-29 19:08:55,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 1
2015-10-29 19:08:55,261 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.util.MapRedUtil - Total input paths to process : 1
(4)
```

How did 10 become 4. Is there a different way to count the number of records in an avro file using PIG?

Comment: I would dump the intermediate results to see what is going on and where the problem could be..

Comment: It looks like its only loading 4 records. Successfully read 4 records (58507 bytes) from: "/user/admin/2015/10/04/02/file1.avro"